# Am I writing something wrong when inserting variable in $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

My variable doesn't get inserted in my database. Can anybody see why? All other fields get inserted in my table except for the `$target_file`.
Have I written something wrong or should `$_POST` variables be written a different way?

```
$target_dir = "images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image1"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["image1"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image1"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}

// Perform queries 
mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM imgtest");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO imgtest (fname, lname, image1)VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$_POST['$target_file']."')");

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: yeah this `$_POST['$target_file']` that's wrong for a few reasons. Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: `@Giovanni Baya` i think it should be `$target_file` instead of `$_POST['$target_file']`

Comment: Agreed $target_file is a variable and not an element of the POST array.

Comment: Giovanni, you've been given answers below. Take your pick. As for "why it's wrong and for a few reasons...", we're dealing with FILES here and not POST. Plus, a variable inside a POST array; doesn't work that way. Had you been checking for errors, it would have given you an indication as to what you are doing wrong. Consult http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO imgtest (fname, lname, image1)VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$_POST['$target_file']."')");
```

try this

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO imgtest (fname, lname, image1)VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$target_file."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

$target_file is already a variable. Remove the $_POST[].

Used this

```
 mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO imgtest (fname, lname, image1)VALUES ('".$_POST['fname']."', '".$_POST['lname']."', '".$target_file."')");
```